# Erro de exibição na tabela jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

Olá, estou tentando exibir alguns dados que pego por ajax e colocá-los em uma tabela responsiva usando o framework Jquery Mobile.

O problema é que, na primeira vez que eu faço a operação, funciona normalmente, porém já na segunda vez, alguns elementos aparecem diferentes. Detalhe: em telas grandes funciona, porém o desenvolvimento é voltado para mobile.

(nomes da campos meramente ilustrativos)

Segue tabela html:

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Q#BR</th>
      <th data-priority="1">campo1</th>
      <th data-priority="1">campo2</th>
      <th data-priority="1">campo3</th>
      <th data-priority="1">campo4</th>
      <th data-priority="2">campo5</th>
      <th data-priority="2">campo6</th>
      <th data-priority="2">campo7</th>
      <th data-priority="2">campo8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb_detail">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Segue código js:

```
function buildTableDetail(p_sts,p_ar){

     $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       url:'http://localhost/arquivos/meu_arquivo.php?callback=?',
       dataType:'jsonp',
       data: {p1:p_ar,
              p2:p_sts},
       beforeSend: function(){

       }    


    }).done(function(data){
         $('#tb_detail').empty();


         for (i = 0; i < data.dados.length; i++) { 
             $('#tb_detail').append('<tr> <td>'+data.dados[i].campo1+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo2+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo3+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo4+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo5+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo6+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo7+
                                    '</td><td>'+data.dados[i].campo8+'</td></tr>');

            }

         $('#link').attr('href','#pg_alvo');
                $('#link').click();
         $('#pg_alvo').bind('pageinit', function () {
            $('#tb_detail').table('refresh');
        });

     })

     .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Erro na operação.");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
     })

}
```

Print da primeira e segunda vez:

**reparem que na segunda já está mostrando os outros campos sem eu pedir, e também mostra um bloco preto ao invés do título da coluna

[image: Print: reparem que na segunda já está mostrando os outros campos sem eu pedir, e também mostra um bloco preto ao invés do título da coluna]

Como poderia concertar isso para sempre aparecer de forma correta?(como na primeira tela)

**EDIT:**

Só para explicar melhor, o problema não está em puxar e mostrar os dados. Isso eu consigo fazer. O problema está no funcionamento errado da tabela com columntoggle, que não esconde as colunas e dados que deveria esconder, mesmo tendo a classe ui-table-cell-hidden ativada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Montei um fiddle simplificado com o que tu mostras e com a tua ajuda consegui perceber qual é o problema:

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bertolo/0s18tzoe/)

Parece que há uma incompatibilidade entre as versões do jquery e jquery mobile.
Para a versão 1.4.5 deve-se usar jQuery da 1.8 até 1.11 ou 2.1.

Comment: O problema é o seguinte: defini 5 campos com prioridade 1(imagem 1) que são exibidos corretamente na primeira vez quando pego os dados por ajax e jogo no formulário, e, por ser uma tabela do tipo "columntoggle", eu também recebo os outros, mas eles ficam escondidos, até que eu queira vê-los clicando no botão "Columns". Porém, a partir da 2ª vez, esses campos que estavam "escondidos" são mostrados direto, e seu título(<th>) não é mostrado, aparecendo o bloco preto(imagem 2) no lugar.

Comment: Consegues montar um fiddle onde reproduzas o erro?

Comment: O fiddle é exatamente igual ao seu, porém com o css e js do Jquery mobile. O meu age igual ao seu, puxando e mostrando os dados, porém devido ao css do Jquery Mobile, algumas colunas deviam ser escondidas, o que não acontece

Comment: Então mas faz fork e mete lá essa mecânica de esconder colunas

Comment: Tentei colocar mas quando atualizo nao pega os estilos. A única coisa que tem que fazer é adicionar <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> e também  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

Comment: Mete lá o código e manda o link que eu já vejo isso

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mokvojbe/ 
Porém não está pegando os estilos.

Comment: dei um jeito nisto: https://jsfiddle.net/bertolo/0s18tzoe/ e reparei numa pormenor muito importante. A funcionalidade de disabilitar colunas não funcionou com jQuery 2.2 e funcionou com 1.12.2. Reparei agora no site que para a versão 1.4.5 deves usar jQuery da 1.8 até 1.11 ou 2.1, portanto o teu problema pode vir daqui. Confirma se funciona para eu editar a minha resposta!

Comment: Entendo, testei e parece que funcionou, porém não vou poder usar pois trocando a versão todo meu layout fica desconfigurado. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.